# Nested reduce function not working for my array of array objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am building a store which can receive orders which I have simulated here with the order arrays. Those orders can contain several different items which I am representing with the name property in the item objects inside the order arrays. And those items can have any quantity aswell.

What I need to to calculate the total amount of units that have been sold of a certain item type. This means I need to loop through all the items in all the orders, and if the item is the type I am looking for, then I need to add that items quantity to the total amount of units for that type.

I made this nested reduce function, but for some reason it is giving the wrong awnsers. What am I doing worng?

```js
const order_1 = [
  { name: "1", quantity: 1 },
  { name: "2", quantity: 3 },
];
const order_2 = [
  { name: "3", quantity: 1 },
  { name: "1", quantity: 2 },
];
const order_3 = [
  { name: "4", quantity: 1 },
  { name: "2", quantity: 1 },
];
const order_4 = [
  { name: "2", quantity: 2 },
  { name: "1", quantity: 1 },
];
const orders = [order_1, order_2, order_3, order_4];

function getTotalQuantity(type) {
  return orders.reduce((prevOrder, currOrder) => {
    return prevOrder + currOrder.reduce((prevItem, currItem) => {
      return prevItem + (currItem.name === type) ? currItem.quantity : 0;
    }, 0);
  }, 0);
}
console.log("1: " + getTotalQuantity("1"));
console.log("2: " + getTotalQuantity("2"));
console.log("3: " + getTotalQuantity("3"));
console.log("4: " + getTotalQuantity("4"));
```

Comment: You're never using `type` anywhere in the function. Is `currItem.name == "1"` supposed to be `currItem.name == type`?

Comment: @Barmar Thanks you, but this was just my bad when writing the question, the function is still not returning the correct awnsers, I updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. You never use `type`
2. Your parenthesis are incorrect

Should be:

```
(currItem.name === type ? currItem.quantity : 0)
```

And not:

```
(currItem.name === type) ? currItem.quantity : 0
```

```js
const order_1 = [
  { name: "1", quantity: 1 },
  { name: "2", quantity: 3 },
];
const order_2 = [
  { name: "3", quantity: 1 },
  { name: "1", quantity: 2 },
];
const order_3 = [
  { name: "4", quantity: 1 },
  { name: "2", quantity: 1 },
];
const order_4 = [
  { name: "2", quantity: 2 },
  { name: "1", quantity: 1 },
];
const orders = [order_1, order_2, order_3, order_4];

function getTotalQuantity(type) {
  return orders.reduce((prevOrder, currOrder) => {
    return prevOrder + currOrder.reduce((prevItem, currItem) => {
      return prevItem + (currItem.name === type ? currItem.quantity : 0);
    }, 0);
  }, 0);
}
console.log("1: " + getTotalQuantity("1"));
console.log("2: " + getTotalQuantity("2"));
console.log("3: " + getTotalQuantity("3"));
console.log("4: " + getTotalQuantity("4"));
```

Also, this new code works fine, but I would use this (less efficient, but more readable):

```js
const order_1 = [
  { name: "1", quantity: 1 },
  { name: "2", quantity: 3 },
];
const order_2 = [
  { name: "3", quantity: 1 },
  { name: "1", quantity: 2 },
];
const order_3 = [
  { name: "4", quantity: 1 },
  { name: "2", quantity: 1 },
];
const order_4 = [
  { name: "2", quantity: 2 },
  { name: "1", quantity: 1 },
];
const orders = [order_1, order_2, order_3, order_4];

function getTotalQuantity(type) {
  return orders.flat().filter(item => item.name === type).reduce((prevItem, currItem) => {
    return prevItem + currItem.quantity;
  }, 0);
}
console.log("1: " + getTotalQuantity("1"));
console.log("2: " + getTotalQuantity("2"));
console.log("3: " + getTotalQuantity("3"));
console.log("4: " + getTotalQuantity("4"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixing with `currItem.name === type ? prevItem + currItem.quantity : prevItem;` is working fine now

```js
const order_1 = [
  { name: "1", quantity: 1 },
  { name: "2", quantity: 3 },
];
const order_2 = [
  { name: "3", quantity: 1 },
  { name: "1", quantity: 2 },
];
const order_3 = [
  { name: "4", quantity: 1 },
  { name: "2", quantity: 1 },
];
const order_4 = [
  { name: "2", quantity: 2 },
  { name: "1", quantity: 1 },
];
const orders = [order_1, order_2, order_3, order_4];

function getTotalQuantity(type) {
  return orders.reduce((prevOrder, currOrder) => {
    return (
      prevOrder +
      currOrder.reduce((prevItem, currItem) => {
        return currItem.name === type ? prevItem + currItem.quantity : prevItem;
      }, 0)
    );
  }, 0);
}

console.log("1: " + getTotalQuantity("1"));
console.log("2: " + getTotalQuantity("2"));
console.log("3: " + getTotalQuantity("3"));
console.log("4: " + getTotalQuantity("4"));
```

Another version with simple `forEach`

```js
const order_1 = [
  { name: "1", quantity: 1 },
  { name: "2", quantity: 3 },
];
const order_2 = [
  { name: "3", quantity: 1 },
  { name: "1", quantity: 2 },
];
const order_3 = [
  { name: "4", quantity: 1 },
  { name: "2", quantity: 1 },
];
const order_4 = [
  { name: "2", quantity: 2 },
  { name: "1", quantity: 1 },
];
const orders = [order_1, order_2, order_3, order_4];

function getTotalQuantity(type, sum = 0) {
  orders.forEach((arr) =>
    arr.forEach(({ name, quantity }) => {
      if (name === type) {
        sum += quantity;
      }
    })
  );
  return sum;
}

console.log("1: " + getTotalQuantity("1"));
console.log("2: " + getTotalQuantity("2"));
console.log("3: " + getTotalQuantity("3"));
console.log("4: " + getTotalQuantity("4"));
```